# Is there an undo, reset or clear capability in mPDF?

Tags: php, mpdf

Is there a way, after calling `$mpdf->WriteHTML( $html )` to either call "undo" or reset it back to a blank state?

I've looked [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/) and found nothing so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `DeletePages()` function to delete / reset the content

Comment: Thank you. That's not documented in the documentation so I didn't know it existed. But what's the difference between that and the `Reset()` function? Is that not the way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 1.7.5 version of Mpdf and now I am confused and devastated. I was trying to use same Mpdf instance for multiple documents (config dependant). I was trying to make it this way:

```
// for each document
$this->mpdf->WriteHtml($content);
$this->mpdf->Output($path, Destination::FILE);
// below does pretty much nothing O.o
$this->mpdf->DeletePages(0, $this->mpdf->PagesNo());
$this->mpdf->Reset();
```

Without `DeletePages()` on second document content of PDF file was bizarre. Text was from first file, title from second, file size suggested two files merged and content was sum of pages, where after content of first document pages were blank (not empty as white, but blank, as transparent). The only difference after using `DeletePages()` was that content was only first document with title from second (in metadata).

For me, the only solution was not to inject `Mpdf` into my Service, but 'generator': function without arguments that hid initiation of Mpdf and on call provided new 'fresh' `Mpdf` instance.